# java out of memory then exit

Tags: java, memory, jvm, out-of-memory, exit

I have a piece of software that has to analyze big files. Constraining the input or giving infinite memory is not an option, so I have to live with flying OOMEs. Because the OOME only kills the Thread, my software runs in some crappy state.

From outside everything looks okay because the process is running but on the inside it's braindead.

I would like to pull the plug on it. But how can I do this?

Catching a OOME does not guranteee that the next line of code will be executed. e.g System.exit(9). So the JVM has to notice OOME and destory itself.

Is their some vm option for this?

Comment: *"Catching a OOME does not guranteee that the next line of code will be executed."* You have a reference for that?

Answer (score 8):

When you get an OOME you can be very low on memory and logging doesn't always work.  One way around this is to have a shutdown method which holds some memory it doesn't release until its shutting down.

e.g.

```
 private static byte[] lastResort = new byte[256*1024];
 public static void handleOOME(OutOfMemoryError oome) {
     lastResort = null;
     try {
        LOG.fatal("Dying after ", oome);
     } finally {
        System.exit(-1);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Interesting approach! Do you have that in production somewhere?

Comment: Brave, exotic, outrageous :p

Comment: @JoachimSauer I did use this in production with 64KB reserved.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` - supported by Java 8 update 92.

You can also use `-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError` to get the core dump for further investigation.

You can also use `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to generate a heap dump on OOME for further investigation.

Source: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40905786/435605) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/JRCLR/optionxx.htm#BABCDAIB).

Answer (score 2):

> So the JVM has to notice OOME and destroy itself.  Is their some vm option for this?

No there is not.

However, I have to question your assumption that you cannot catch an `OutOfMemoryError` and  and immediately call `System.exit()` in the exception handler.

In practice it should work.  The only potential problem is if you have called `Runtime.setRunFinalizersOnExit(true)` ... and even that is ignored if you exit with a non-zero exit status.

(The caveat about catching OOME's and other random `Error` exceptions is that the JVM may not be in a fit state *to continue executing*.  But calling `System.exit(nonzero)` ain't doing that!)

Comment: It does work, I've written a Swing program that catches an OutOfMemoryError then puts a message to the screen about it.

Comment: The act of catching an OOME several levels down the call stack **might** free enough memory for some basic logging/error handling (because the GC roots from the call stacks disappear).

Comment: That is true, and @Peter Lawrey's answer is another approach.  (I've seen it in other contexts.  For instances, some JVMs do this kind of thing to reserve space for creating the OOME and its stack frames.)